# Create and Deploy an Azure Function at Blob Container Creation in C# Code

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a (.net core C#) API to handle image upload, retrieve, delete, etc. Images are uploaded to blob containers, that are dynamically created from the code, with a name given with the POST request when uploading an image. There is also a blob trigger function deployed in Azure to create resized low-quality image for each image uploaded for a given blob container. There is a need to duplicate this image resize function app for each new container that is created. IF duplicated, I need to bind the new container names as the source and destination containers of the new instance of the image-resize function app, AND deploy it in the same resource group as the first function app.

Is there any way I can achieve all of this from the C# code? If not from the code, how can I do this?

Comment: If you want to create new azure function for each blob container dynamically? I think that is not the correct idea. How you will update code?

Comment: @PankajRawat Azure function code will remain the same, only the container names have to be passed to the bindings. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I don't think you do this kind of activity with Azure function, Azure function run under sandbox with limited permission.

Comment: Somehow If you are able to achieve, how you will deploy new code? If you're deploying code through CI/CD or manually that will deploy in single function? how rest of functiion will update?

Comment: I would recommend, to handle all blob storage changes through single function. You can use EventGrid to listen changes from your blob and take appropriate action.

Comment: @PankajRawat If I use an event grid, can I dynamically plug new blob containers to the event grid whenever a new container is created? Without having to do it manually?

Comment: I Added my answer below, hope it will help! Similar practise Microsoft has recommended for storage account manual backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try [EventGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-quickstart#subscribe-to-your-storage-account) for your requirement. Below image give you a high idea you can change some component according to your business requirement.

[image]

EventGrid Topic built-in with storage account so you don't need to create separately.

[image]

You can filter which event you want to listen.

[image]

Then you can route your message to the appropriate endpoint (Azure Function Or Queue)

[image]

If you're storing resize images in the same storage account you will get an event for those images, You can put some logic to filter those image from your Function.

You will not face any [latency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#alternatives) issue with EventGrid while Blob trigger has some latency issue.

Comment: Thank you! I switched to an event grid trigger function app as you have suggested and managed to get the task done.